# Why doesn't the Green Lantern ring do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, superman-red-son

In the movie *Superman: Red Son* when the US finds the Green Lantern alien,

> why doesn't his ring fly off and find a replacement?

**From what I understand:**  When a Green Lantern dies, the green power ring soars to the closest qualified alien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible explanation is that Abin Sur was (artificially) comatose and not dead, therefor his ring would not seek a new owner.

A second explanation might be that in this reality, just like many other things that have changed surrounding Superman/Wonder Woman/Batman that this is no longer a thing.

This allowed Luthor to reverse engineer the rings making new ones that don't have the same user requirements as the original rings.

But it could also just be a plothole seeing it is never explained in the movie.

Comment: Yup, the Green Lantern must be dead for the ring to "fly off" and seek new worthy wearer. As long as the person that ring chosen is not dead the ring cannot be removed.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY The ring can be removed due to lack of concentration as Batman has done once in the animated movie series this one is a part of.